# How do detect input field changed when selecting from a datalist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input with attached datalist:

```
<input type="text" list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
<option>1
<option>2
</datalist>
```

When I choose an option from the list then the `change` event doesn't fire on the input element. So how can I detect input's change?

Comment: you can use Jquery to detect the change. eg $(‘#input-or-select-element-id‘).change(function(){});

Comment: it sounds like he's already using the `$.change()` function

Comment: No value set - therefore no change is happening?

Comment: @below9k that sounds right.. he needs to show his code.

Comment: @CodeGodie just FYI, the way of talking about jquery functions that belong to the matching set is `$.fn.change`

Comment: There's no code to show! Everything's in the question. Silly people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the `input` event:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  alert('Changed!');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
<option>1
<option>2
</datalist>
```

**Update**

I didn't notice the jQuery tag at first, and @YanickRochon made a good point that this should also capture the change event.

**New Snippet**

```js
$('input').on('input change', function() {
  alert('Changed!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
<option>1
<option>2
</datalist>
```

Comment: I +1'd you, but I'd specify `input` *and* `change`. Also, he's specified that jQuery is being used, here. So : `$('input').on('input change', ...);`

Comment: @yanick-rochon there is no single word about jQuery. So give +1 ;)

Comment: @yanick-rochon sorry for spam but +1 for you.

Comment: @RickHitchcock you're welcome! and **lujcon**, no harm done, I can understand how tags can be misread sometimes. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the 'input' event does the trick. Didn't even know there is such an event!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [input](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php) event, like this

```
$('#input-list').on('input change', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/kitocu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input').on('input', function () {
      alert("changed");
   })

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fd57ku85/)

Answer (score 2):

### All other answers are not differentiating between input scenarios

The question is about how to **specifically** know when an input was changed by a `datalist` and **not** by anything else. This is **very** important to differentiate.

The below code will absolutely differentiate between a user input either by *typing*, *pasting* via the keyboard or via mouse or any other way, and between actually selecting an option from a `<datalist>`

```js
var noneDatalistInput;

$('input').on('keydown paste', onNoneDatalistInput)
          .on('input', onInput);

// raise a flag
function onNoneDatalistInput(e){
    if( e.key == "Enter" ) return;
    if( noneDatalistInput ) clearTimeout(noneDatalistInput);
    noneDatalistInput = setTimeout(function(){ noneDatalistInput = null }, 50);
}

function onInput(){
    var isDatalistInput = !noneDatalistInput;
    console.log('was a datalist option selected? ', isDatalistInput);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" list="mylist">

<datalist id="mylist">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score -1):

are you listening to INPUT change? or DataList Change?

```
// wont work
$("#myList").on('change', function () {
    alert("yay!");
});

// fires yay! when change value (after focus out)
$("#myText").on('change', function () {
    alert("yay!");
});
```

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6LdLfyo/2/)